# Insert unique pair values from another table with select/join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, insert

So I have a table which looks something like this:

```
[sides]
--------------------
left | right
A    | B
A    | C
A    | D
B    | A
--------------------
```

Note that the first and the last rows are the same value pairs. What I need to do is insert all unique pairs into another table, which would look like this after executed on the above table:

```
[pairs]
------------------
val1  |  val2
A     |  B
A     |  C
A     |  D
------------------
```

So far I have this code:

```
INSERT INTO pairs (val1, val2)
SELECT DISTINCT s1.left, s1.right
FROM sides s1;
```

As you can see it's only copies the pairs but not a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
INSERT INTO pairs(val1, val2)
    SELECT DISTINCT least(s1.left, s1.right), greatest(s1.left, s1.right)
    FROM sides s1;
```

EDIT:

The above should work (you can test the `select` separately).  You can also do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO pairs(val1, val2)
    SELECT s1.left, s1.right
    FROM sides s1
    WHERE s1.left < s1.right
    union all
    SELECT s1.left, s1.right
    FROM sides s1
    WHERE s1.left > s1.right and
          not exists (select 1
                      from sides s2
                      where s1.left = s2.right and s1.right = s2.left
                     );
```

This version can take advantage of an index on `sides(left, right)`.

Comment: I don't know why but it's just freezes and waits for execution but doesn't looks like anything is happening.

Comment: UPDATE: tried the edited code, now it says "unique constraint violated.  An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.". My keys in the pairs table are the val1 and val2.

Comment: @CompanyCodeMonkey . . . Ooops, I left out one of the all-important conditions.